# WebStorm lags when I type

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I am running the 64 bit version of WebStorm 2016.1.1, and it lags every few characters that I type. I've tried disabling plugins and increasing the max allocated memory to 8GB, but the performance hasn't improved.

It doesn't lag for a fresh new project so it must be my project size.  However, I have not typed up that much code (< 5k lines), so I've concluded it must be all my `node_modules`.

I've marked my `build` directory and `node_modules` directory as excluded, but for some reason only the build directory appears in red (which is the color of an excluded directory). The `node_modules` appears in my list of excluded directories when I check my settings, but it still appears yellow in the project list:

[image]

The only other thing I can think of that seems suspicious is that it says "library root" next to node_modules, but I haven't been able to find much info on that.

I am completely out of ideas.  What on earth could the problem be that's causing the editor to lag so bad?

Comment: It quite possibly could be your `node_modules`. Go to your `JavaScript | Libraries` in your IDE Settings/Preferences and unmark (or maybe even delete, but later, after checking how unmarking will perform) that library/those libraries. P.S. You may also want to try (to see if there will be any better) the [2016.2 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-232/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`node_modules` directory is set up as a JavaScript Library. Libraries can't be excluded from indexing, thus excluding `node_modules` does nothing. 
Please remove it from libraries (`Preferences (Settings)/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Libraries`, select '`<project name> node_modules`' there, press Remove, OK). Then make sure that node_modules is shown as excluded.

Further investigations revealed problems updating VCS checklists. It is fixed in [WebStorm 2016.2 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)

Comment: I removed it from the libraries and re-excluded it.  The folder is now red and no longer says "library root" next to it.  Unfortunately, the problem persists.  Thanks for trying to help. I'll submit a support ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case the problem was because I changed the "Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard" under Editor->General to 100. The problem subsided after I set it to lower numbers such as 10.